# Optional arguments in the `\newtcolorbox` macro

Tags: tcolorbox

According to [the `tcolorbox` package's user manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), the `\newtcolorbox` macro's usage is as follows (p. 15).

[image: newtcolorbox]

The following is given as a usage example. (p. 15).

[image: newtcolorbox usage example]

Here's what I don't understand about this example.

1. In the definition part: What do the empty square brackets mean? That there are no defaults, i.e. that the 2 options are mandatory? If so, why not simply omit these brackets, as in the following example that is given on the same page?

[image: A mandatory option]

2. In the usage part: Why is the first argument (`[colback=yellow]`) written within square brackets, whereas the second argument (`{Hello there`}) written within curly braces? If there were more than 2 arguments, how would they be specified?

Comment: this is the same syntax for optional argument definitions as `\newcommand` which also can only declare commands with a single optional argument, (optional arguments in latex are always in `[]` to answer your 2nd question)

Comment: There *is* a default, and it's empty. The empty set is different from “no set”, isn't it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition is analogous to what is offered by `\newcommand` where you can define something via

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}[2][x]{optional: #1, mandatory: #2}
```

which defines a command `\mycmd` to take two arguments `[2]`. The first argument is optional and will take the value `x` if you don't use it. So, `\mycmd{a}` is valid, as is `\mycmd[b]{a}`.

Specific to your questions:

> 1. In the definition part: What do the empty square brackets mean? That there are no defaults, i.e. that the 2 options are mandatory? If so, why not simply omit these brackets, as in the following example that is given on the same page?

The empty square brackets refer to the fact that the newly-defined `tcolorbox` command will take a *single* optional argument, and the default value for that optional argument if it isn't specified by the user will be blank.

> 2. In the usage part: Why is the first argument (`[colback=yellow]`) written within square brackets, whereas the second argument (`{Hello there}`) written within curly braces? If there were more than 2 arguments, how would they be specified?

This is because the creation of `mybox` was defined with

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]
```

in the first and

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]
```

in the second.

The first states that `mybox` will take two arguments `[2]` of which the first will be optional and default to "blank" if not supplied. The second states that `mybox` will only take a single argument `[1]` and that it is a mandatory argument.

If you want, say, 5 arguments, all mandatory, then you'd use

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[5]
```

If you want a single, optional argument, together with (say) 3 mandatory arguments, then use

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][default]
```

where `default` is the default definition of the optional argument if it's not specified. Moreover, the optional argument is always the first `#1` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. There can never be more than a single optional argument?

Comment: @EvanAad: With the default usage in `\newtcolorbox`, no. It matches what you can do with `\newcommand` which provides only a single, optional argument. However, that's usually what is sufficient, as you can define key-value combinations in the optional argument that covers multiple scenarios. There is also `\DeclareTColorBox` for specifying a varied interface as can be seen in [Christian's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371444/5764).

Answer (score 10):

The `[]` is empty here in the first example, but allows for specification of optional arguments to the call of the mybox environment, i.e. `\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Foo}` title would have a yellow background and the the title foo. The second example would not allow for optional arguments, that's all.

The definition of box environments with two or more mandatory arguments is as usual with `\newcommand`: `\newtcolorbox{foo}[2]{options}`.

If more optional arguments are necessary, use the `\DeclareTColorBox` feature of `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}


\newtcolorbox{myboxwithtwoparameters}[2]{colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,code={\addtocontents{toc}{#2}}}


\DeclareTColorBox{mytotalbox}{O{}mO{-2mm}}{colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=#3},
title=#2,#1}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mybox}

\begin{myboxwithtwoparameters}{Hello there}{Hello Darkness my old friend}
Foo
\end{myboxwithtwoparameters}

\begin{mytotalbox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}[-5mm]
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mytotalbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]